# How to find out if HDD is ATA or AHCI?

Tags: batch-file, ata

From a batch file how would you find if a hard drive is ATA or AHCI? Is it stored somewhere in a file I can parse or is there a command to find out?

Comment: I notice that you have several accepted answers but haven't case any votes. Just a friendly FYI, you can also upvote answers you accept, by clicking the up arrow above the number to the left of the answer (and generally should, unless for some odd reason you don't think the answer you accepted was particularly useful).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be better methods but this detects AHCI here:

```
wmic idecontroller|find /i "ahci">nul && echo AHCI detected
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use DXDIAG.  Something like this:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET DxDiag=%TEMP%\DxDiag.txt
IF EXIST %DxDiag% DEL /q %DxDiag%

ECHO.Getting DxDiag information for %ComputerName%
ECHO.Please wait...
SET "DxDiagArgs="
REM DxDiag does not work with /64 bit on end, or with quotes on filename
REM START will not wait for 32 bit DxDiag on 64 bit machine
IF DEFINED PROGRAMFILES(x86) SET "DxDiagArgs=%DxDiagArgs%/64bit "
SET DxDiagArgs=%DxDiagArgs%/whql:off /t %DxDiag%
START "" /BELOWNORMAL /WAIT DXDIAG.EXE %DxDiagArgs%

IF NOT EXIST %DxDiag% (
   ECHO.DxDiag not available.
   GOTO :Done
   )

ECHO.
ECHO.Search for the "Disk & DVD/CD-ROM Drives" section in 
ECHO.%DxDiag%
ECHO.and parse what you want out of it.
ECHO.

:Done
PAUSE
IF EXIST %DxDiag% DEL /q %DxDiag%
```

You will find something like this for each ATA drive:
      Model: SAMSUNG HD642JJ ATA Device